# React-Router-DOM not actually creating routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0, react-router-dom

I followed a tutorial to set up `Auth0` on a simple create-react-app. The only thing I have in the project as of now is authentication and routing. When developing in *localhost*, the app worked fine:

- / routed to `/home`, and showed the current signed-in status
- /home routed to `/home`, ^
- /callback, called by the authentication service, routed fine and handles the authentication and redirects to a logged in page.

As I mentioned, all of this routing worked fine on development. I was able to see a login page, press login, login with credentials, get rerouted through `/callback` back to the homepage and see material only available if you're logged in. I was then able to log out and be routed correctly again back to the login page.

I deployed the app to a website (https://dashboard.xxxxx.com) but none of the routes work except /. So https://dashboard.xxxxx.com works, but https://dashboard.xxxxx.com/home nor https://dashboard.xxxxx.com/callback cannot be found.

This causes the `auth0` service to fail logging in because it redirects to https://dashboard.xxxxx.com/callback but that page does not exist.

I started off using Router from `react-router-dom` with just Routes, then I tried Router with a Switch and Routes. I then tried `BrowserRouter` and then `HashRouter`, but none have worked. My current code is below:

```
    <HashRouter history={history} component={Home}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props}/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/home' render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props}/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/callback' render={(props) => {
                handleAuth(props);
                return <Callback {...props}/>
            }}/>
        </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are not redirecting all requests to `index.html` from server which is used to initialise your application.
You need to redirect all call to index.html from server side may be in `.htaccess` file, node or any other framework you would be using.

Locally the redirection to `index.html` is handled by Create-react-app if you are using that or any other way.

Comment: I am using netlify: is this what I'm looking for? https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/

Comment: With netifly it is damn simple. Refer to this [link](https://www.edwardbeazer.com/routing-react-apps-hosted-on-netlify/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly